# Need help splitting a file with blanc lines (BASH)

Tags: bash

I have a file containing several few thousands of lines. The file format is similar to this:

```
1
H
H    13.1641870     7.1039560    -5.9652740

3
O2H2
H    15.5567440     5.6184980    -4.5255100
H    15.8907030     4.2338600    -5.4917990
O    15.5020000     6.4310000    -7.0960000
O    13.7940000     5.5570000    -8.1620000

2
CH
H    13.0960830     7.7155820    -3.5224750
C    11.0480000     7.4400000    -5.5080000

.
.
.
.
```

What I want is to split the full file in several files where putting in each file all the information between empty lines. The problem is that the blank lines do not follow a pattern. Some parts of the text have 1 line and others have 10.

Could someone tell me how to separate the file using the blank lines as separator?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also s.o. has a lot  of entries/post about *splitting files*

Answer (score 0):

Using awk and the data in a file called mainfile

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS="[\n]+" } { print $0 >> "file"NR".txt" }' mainfile
```

Set the record separator to one or more line feeds and then print each record to a file dictated by the record number i.e. file1.txt etc

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk -v RS="" '{print > "file" ++i ".txt"; close("file" i ".txt")}' input.txt
```

- If the awk variable `RS` is set to the null string, then records are separated by blank lines.
- It is recommended to close each file to avoid the "too many open files" error.